# Is there any way to add a key to a sub/module in l3keys?

Tags: expl3, comma-separated-list, l3keys

I need to loop through a comma-separated list, creating them all as keys for a data structure.
I can't think of a way to loop through the keys *inside* `\keys_define:nn`, so the only other option I see is to put `\keys_define` into the loop.

Is there any way I can *augment* a keys module, instead of simply redefining it?

I am using LaTeX3's `clist` for the comma-separated list.

---

By 'augment,' think of set union.
Say you have a set of keys `S` in a module `module`.
When I augment `module` with a key `k`, I want the set of keys in `module` to be `S \union {k}`.

If the `S` itself may be accessed (outside of the context of the module?), then I *could* simply redefine the module with `S` and `k`.  This module should only be able to grow—a separate means will be provided to clear it.

Comment: I don't follow '_augment_ .. instead of simply redefining': could you elaborate?

Comment: You can use `\keys_define:nn { allred } { ... }` as many times as you want.

Comment: @JosephWright Absolutely—see my edit.

Comment: @egreg of course, but doesn't this redefine the `allred` module completely?

Comment: @SeanAllred Not in my test.

Comment: I couldn't figure a way to test it... perhaps this should then be closed for some reason or another?  If the behavior I want to ensure is already the default...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a test that shows that new keys are added to the set for each `\keys_define:nn` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {test}
 {
  a .tl_set:N = \l_test_a_tl,
 }
\keys_define:nn {test}
 {
  b .tl_set:N = \l_test_b_tl,
 }
\keys_set:nn {test} { a=a, b=b }

\clist_map_inline:nn
 { 
  c .tl_set:N = \l_test_c_tl,
  d .tl_set:N = \l_test_d_tl,
 }
 {
  \keys_define:nn { test } { #1 }
 }

\keys_set:nn {test}
 {
  c = c,
  d = d
 }

\tl_show:N \l_test_a_tl
\tl_show:N \l_test_b_tl
\tl_show:N \l_test_c_tl
\tl_show:N \l_test_d_tl
```