# Log all keys in a module

Tags: expl3, debugging, logging, l3keys

Using `l3keys`, is there any way to inspect the keys currently in a (sub)module?
I'm looking for something like `\clist_show`, but for keys.

`\keys_show` sounded promising, but requires that you already know the keys that have been created: `\keys_show:nn {<module>} {<key>}`.

My ideal scenario would be:

```
\keys_show:n {module}
There are 4 keys in the key module 'module' (without outer braces):
>    {this} tl
>    {is}   tl
>    {a}    tl
>    {test} bool
```

Comment: I know it can be done (at least to the effect), given [@egreg's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127735/is-there-any-way-to-add-a-key-to-a-sub-module-in-l3keys?noredirect=1#comment287385_127735).

Comment: Update: a good complete solution for this might involve some trickery; the test egreg provided in his answer was much simpler in concept than I had imagined…

Comment: Right now, we don't keep track anywhere of the list of keys (this is similar to why you can't get a list of all macros defined at a given time in TeX).  In principle we could add an option to collect all keys somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Bruno says in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127743/log-all-keys-in-a-module#comment291861_127743), the situation here is entirely the same as wanting to list all macros defined. Indeed, key definitions both in `l3keys` and other keyval packages are simply macro names in the 'appropriate' place. TeX doesn't provide us with a route to query the list of defined macros for 'all matching some wildcard scheme', so the only way to have such a command available is to do it 'by hand'. At present, that is not the case in `l3keys`. One can of course imagine doing this, but without a clear use case it is likely to add to the complexity of the code without any general benefit.