# Finding current siunitx settings (or extracting expl3 keys)

Tags: siunitx, expl3

The [siunitx package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) provides a way of formatting (SI) units. It has a plethora of internal settings that the user can set with `\sisetup`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \sisetup{round-precision=2, round-mode=places, round-half=up}
\end{document}
```

will cause `\num{4.485}` to print `4.49`.

My question is, how can I extract the current settings for *siuntx*? For example, above `round-precision` is set to `2`. How can I get *siunitx* to tell me this?

(The *siunitx* package is written using [expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) and I do not understand the key system it uses...)

Comment: If you say `round-precision=2`, what's the purpose of making `siunitx` to tell you what you already know? However, the number is stored in the integer variable `\l__siunitx_process_precision_int` (the name tells it's “private”).

Comment: `\keys_show:nn {siunitx}{round-precision}` will show you that it does `\int_set:Nn \l__siunitx_process_precision_int {#1}` (or you look in `siunitx.sty`).

Comment: @egreg @Qrrbrbirlbel  Sure, in the MWE I know what the settings are but in general I won't as I want to import the current *siunix* settings into some other code. From reading `siunitx.sty` I'd guessed that `round-precision` is stored in `\l__siunitx_process_precision_int` but I can't see how to access this: using `\l__siunitx_process_precision_int`  gives me a "Missing number, treated as zero." error. Are local *expl3* variables inaccessible outside of their namespace? (I wouldn't have thought so since tex does not have namespaces...)

Comment: @Andrew I can access it; probably you tried it without saying `\ExplSyntaxOn` (the `expl3` analog of `\makeatletter`). However, as I said, the variable is “private”, so it's not guaranteed to be used in future releases.

Comment: @egreg I'd used `\ExplSyntaxOn` but I hadn't appreciated that `\l__siunitx_process_precision_int` is a normal tex counter so that I need to use `\the\l__siunitx_process_precision_int` to get its' value. Thanks for explaining the meaning of local/private *expl3* variables.

Comment: @Andrew Not `\the\..` better `\int_use:N \l__siunitx_process_precision_int`.

Comment: Possibly related: [Log all keys in a module](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127743/17423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `LuaLaTeX` you can parse your imported file and access the `siunitx` parameters, and even resuse them :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,siunitx}

\begin{luacode}
function SiunitxSplit ( file )
    local param
    local i = 1

    local f = assert(io.open(file, "r"))
    local t = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    for param in t:gmatch ("\\sisetup(%b{})")
    do
        param = param:sub(2,-2)
        tex.print (i.."--"..param..":\\\\")
        param = param:gsub("%s","")
        param = param:gsub("([^,]+)",
            function (s)
            s=s:gsub("([^=]+)=([^=]+)" , "%1 is : %2")
            return s
            end
            )
        param = param:gsub(",","\\\\")
        tex.print (param.."\\paragraph{}")
        i = i + 1
    end
end

function UseSiunitxSettings ( nb , file )
    local param
    local list = {}
    local f = assert(io.open(file, "r"))
    local t = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    for param in t:gmatch ("\\sisetup(%b{})")
    do
        param = param:sub(2,-2)
        table.insert (list, param)
    end
    tex.print ("\\sisetup{"..list[nb].."}" )
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\SiunitxSplit}[1]{%
    \directlua{SiunitxSplit("#1")}
}

\newcommand{\UseSiunitxSettings}[2][1]{%
    \directlua{UseSiunitxSettings(#1 , "#2")}
}


\begin{document}

\SiunitxSplit{bob.tex}

\UseSiunitxSettings{bob.tex}

\num{3.14159}

\UseSiunitxSettings[2]{bob.tex}

\num{3.14159}

\end{document}
```

and bob.tex contains as part :

```
\sisetup{round-precision=2, round-mode=places, round-half=up}
\sisetup{round-precision=3, round-mode=places, round-half=up}
```

Comment: I don't use LuaTex but at least this answers my question:)

Answer (score 4):

As observed in comments, the key settings are (largely) stored in a set of variables which are marked as *private* in `siunitx`. TeX doesn't prevent you accessing these (they are private by convention rather than at any technical level), so you can read the code and then extract the values. However, there is a reason this data is private: there is *no* documented interface for accessing the data and there should be *no reason* to access it.

Comment: One thing I wonder about is whether all key values should be stored systematically. With something like a `.tl_set:N` key there is a place to get the 'value', but that's not the case for a choice or whatever. it's at least arguable that the back end should track all key values.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. The reason that I asked the question was that I was writing code that used `siunitx` and I wanted to be able to extract the `siunitx` settings for use in my code. I eventually realised that my approach was misguided and I found a better way off doing what I wanted. I am still interested in the answer, however, because Manuel's suggestion in the comments to use `\int_use:N \l__siunitx_process_precision_int` doesn't always work...of course, I have forgotten the example I found which I accept may well have been due to user error.